# How to replace old json object with a new one with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, crud

How to replace old json object using NodeJS with a new updated object ?

Right now when i update the json file it saves the new data with the old one.

JSON :

```
[ {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sven",
    "phone": "123123"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Martin",
    "phone": "2342342"
  } ]
```

Here is my code :

```
var operation = POST.operation; // POST request comes with operation = update/insert/delete


        if (operation == 'update') {
            fs.readFile("file.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {

                var jsonFileArr = [];
                jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data); //Parse the data from JSON file                    
                var haveId = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj){ // Checks if the POST request have the same id as JSON file
                    return obj.id == POST.id;
                })

                if (haveId) {  // if true

                    var updateData = []; // Array with POST data
                    updateData.push({
                        id: POST.id,
                        name: POST.name,
                        phone: POST.phone,
                    })
                    jsonFileArr.push(updateData);
                    var newUsers = JSON.stringify(jsonFileArr);
                    fs.writeFile("file.json", newUsers, "utf8");
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })                
        }
```

I should probably use `delete object` but how can i specify what object should be removed ?

So when i update data with id 1 it would delete  the old id / Name / phone and write the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption base on your question is that you have multiple objects in one file. So the easy way to work around this would be to

```
      if (operation == 'update') {
        fs.readFile("file.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {

            var jsonFileArr = [];
            jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data); //Parse the data from JSON file
            var haveId = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj){ // Checks if the POST request have the same id as JSON file
                return obj.id == POST.id;
            })

            if (haveId) {  // if true
                var updateData = []; // Array with POST data
                updateData.push({
                    id: POST.id,
                    name: POST.name,
                    phone: POST.phone,
                })

                for(let Arr of jsonFileArr){
                  if (Arr.id == POST.id){
                    let currentIndex = jsonFileArr.indexOf(Arr);
                    jsonFileArr.splice(currentIndex,1,updateData) //removing the old object and adding the new one
                  }
                }

                var newUsers = JSON.stringify(jsonFileArr);
                fs.writeFile("file.json", '', "utf8",function(err,res){  //Making the file empty
                  if(!err){
                    fs.writeFile("file.json", newUsers, "utf8",function(err,res){ //Writing the whole object back
                      if(err)console.log(err);
                      console.info(res);
                    });
                  }else{
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                });

            }
        })
    }
```

I think this is better instead of using some, get the matching index and replace directly.

```
      var jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data); //Parse the data from JSON file
      var foundId = jsonFileArr.findIndex(function (obj){ // Checks if the POST request have the same id as JSON file
          return obj.id == POST.id;
      });
      if (foundId >= 0) {
        jsonFileArr[foundId] = 
          {
                id: POST.id,
                name: POST.name,
                phone: POST.phone,
          }
      }
```

.... and then write back to file

Comment: Wow thanks , it works ! But can u explain the ' for(var Arr of jsonFileArr) ' Loop. ( replaced let with var because my javascipt doesn't Support let )
I'm prety new.

Comment: [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) iterates over an iterable object, in this case an array. It runs the body of the loop for each item in the array, assigning the name `Arr` to the current item. Node 6+ should have support for `let`; 4 and 5 have [partial support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let) for it, although they don't have the proper block scope.

Comment: @UselessCode, Ye , i get an Block-scoped declaration error when i use 'let'. I think it's time to upgrade :) Thank you for your explanation